# Python GUI Calculator (Backspace and Plus/Minus)

Tags: python

I am creating a simple calculator using Python GUI and I have everything done but I cannot figure out how to write the code for def Backspace(self): and def Plusminus(self):

Right now the backspace button is removing the number or function, but it is not storing it and the next button that you hit everything comes back.

The Plus/Minus is supposed to make the number negative if it is greater than 0 or make it positive if the number is less than 0. Right now it is just putting a negative sign in front and not actually making the number negative.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):


def __init__(self, master):

    super(Application, self).__init__(master)
    self.task = ""
    self.UserIn = StringVar()
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    #Create all the buttons for calculator.
    # User input stored as an Entry widget.

    self.user_input = Entry(self, bg = "White",
    insertwidth = 4, width = 24,
    font = ("Times", 20), textvariable = self.UserIn, justify = RIGHT)
    self.user_input.grid(columnspan = 4)

    self.user_input.insert(0, "0")

    # Button for value 7
    self.button1 = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "7", padx = 40, pady = 20, font = ("Times", 20),
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick(7))
    self.button1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

    # Button for value 8
    self.button2 = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "8",  padx = 40, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick(8), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

    # Button for value 9
    self.button3 = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "9",  padx = 40, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick(9), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.button3.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = W)

    # Button for value 4
    self.button4 = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "4",  padx = 40, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick(4), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.button4.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

    # Button for value 5
    self.button5 = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "5",  padx = 40, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick(5), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.button5.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

    # Button for value 6
    self.button6 = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "6",  padx = 40, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick(6), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.button6.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = W)

    # Button for value 1
    self.button7 = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "1",  padx = 40, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick(1), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.button7.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)

    # Button for value 2
    self.button8 = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "2",  padx = 40, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick(2), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.button8.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

    # Button for value 3
    self.button9 = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "3",  padx = 40, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick(3), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.button9.grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = W)

    # Button for value 0
    self.button9 = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "0",  padx = 40, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick(0), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.button9.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)

    # Operator buttons
    # Addition button
    self.Addbutton = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "+",  padx = 20, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick("+"), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.Addbutton.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = W)

    # Subtraction button
    self.Subbutton = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "-",  padx = 23, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick("-"), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.Subbutton.grid(row = 3, column = 3, sticky = W)

    # Multiplication button
    self.Multbutton = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "*",  padx = 20, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick("*"), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.Multbutton.grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky = W)

    # Division button
    self.Divbutton = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "/",  padx = 23, pady = 20,
    command = lambda : self.buttonClick("/"), font = ("Times", 20))
    self.Divbutton.grid(row = 5, column = 3, sticky = W)

    # Equal button
    self.Equalbutton = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "=",  padx = 98, pady = 20,
    command = self.CalculateTask, font = ("Times", 20))
    self.Equalbutton.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = W, columnspan = 2)

    # Clear Button
    self.Clearbutton = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "C", font = ("Times", 20), padx = 38, pady = 20, command = self.ClearDisplay)
    self.Clearbutton.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    # Backspace Button
    self.Backspace = Button(self, bg = "White",
    text = "<",  padx = 20, pady = 20,
    command = self.Backspace, font = ("Times", 20))
    self.Backspace.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = W)

    # Blank Button
    self.blank = Button(self, bg = 'White',
    text = ' ', padx = 44, pady = 20,
    font = ('Times', 20))
    self.blank.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

    # +/- Button
    self.Plusminus = Button(self, bg = 'White',
    text = '+/-', padx = 31, pady = 20,
    command = self.Plusminus, font = ('Times', 20))
    self.Plusminus.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W)

def buttonClick(self, number):
    self.task = str(self.task) + str(number)
    self.UserIn.set(self.task)

def CalculateTask(self):
    self.data = self.user_input.get()
    try:
        self.answer = eval(self.data)
        self.displayText(self.answer)
        self.task = self.answer

    except SyntaxError as e:
        self.displayText("Invalid Syntax!")
        self.task = ""

def displayText(self, value):
    self.user_input.delete(0, END)
    self.user_input.insert(0, value)

def ClearDisplay(self):
    self.task = ""
    self.user_input.delete(0, END)
    self.user_input.insert(0, "0")

def Backspace(self):
    self.data = self.user_input.get()
    self.user_input.delete(len(self.data)-1, END)

def Plusminus(self):
    self.data = self.user_input.get()
    if self.data.startswith('-'):
        self.user_input.delete(0, 1) # delete the first character

    else:
        self.user_input.insert(0, '-') # add a - to the front
    print(self.data)
    print(self.task)

calculator = Tk()

calculator.title("My Calculator")
app = Application(calculator)
# Make window fixed (cannot be resized)
calculator.resizable(width = False, height = False)

calculator.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you dont update the `self.task` variable, you only modify the user input string.

In Plusminus() after `self.user_input.insert(0, '-')` make

```
self.task = self.user_input.get()
```

Ditto in Backspace().

I also noticed you used `self.Plusminus` as a variable name for a function and also for the widget. Actually, `self.Plusminus` first refers to the function, than when the widget is created, it refers to that afterwards. This is not causing problem for you right now, you should avoid this.